# I want to create candlestick chart from scratch which square grid (not rectangle grid)

Tags: python, charts, grid, trading, square

I've seen a lot of candlestick chart on youtube video and websites and somehow most of them having rectangle grid for some reason.

If I want to create square grid, how do I create code for it and which libraries (mplfinance, plotly, bokeh, bqplot, and cufflinks) are best for creating certain geometrical tool such as such Gann angle 45 degree, Gann square box etc...

Please advise. Thanks

Create candlestick chart from scratch

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the other packages, but **`mplfinance.plot()`** has a kwarg called `figratio` which can modify the aspect ratio of the figure.   You can use `figratio=(1,1)` to create a square figure, and then use `figscale=` to scale the figure up and down to make it larger and smaller.  It also accepts kwarg `figsize=(width,height)` to specify both the size and aspect ratio at the same time.

I don't know about plotly, bokeh, bqplot, and cufflinks, but I imagine they also have similar techniques for modifying the size and/or aspect ratio of your plot figures.  Check their documentation.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will definitely try that